# Can we convert a docker container or a simple nodejs app into EVM bytecode and run it on EVM compositable as smart contracts?

Tags: docker, blockchain, ethereum, polygon, evm

This might sound silly!

I have a thought, what if we built some kind of transpiler or compiler that will take a docker image and run it on EVM basically converting the docker image to EVM bytecode, is it possible?

don't cancel me, just a thought experiment

Comment: No it's not. EVM is stack machine tailed for logic in smart contract. Logic behind docker container or general app doesn't suit to evm

Comment: yeah, that's what I thought, so we need to create our own decentralize networks for this type of thing?